# Starting asmx service when running unit tests

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, continuous-integration, asmx

We have a VS 2010 Solution with many projects.

One of the projects contains asmx services.

We have a problem that our tests fail if the services are not running.

What is the best way to make sure that the services are started when the tests run? We need to get this to work both on the developers machine and on the build server, where we use TFS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution, it was to use `WebDev.WebServer40.exe`